# Asp.Net Core 3x Swagger Multiple Headers for Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, api-key

I'm looking at implementing a simple authentication mechanism based on the old PAT or API-Key in the header system. Ultimately, I want the user to provide two headers during a request that requires authentication. A Client-Id and their Token. In Postman, it simply would look like this:

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VRK3.png)

and have managed to achieve this, largely by adapting to what I found here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61365691/4087918

My definitions look like this

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("API-Key", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description = "API Key required to access the api.",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Name = "API-Key",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
});

c.AddSecurityDefinition("Client-ID", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description = "Client ID required to access the api.",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Name = "Client-ID",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
});

c.OperationFilter<ApiKeyHeaderFilter>();
```

and my filter a little like this:

```
operation.Security.Add(
    new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "API-Key",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Reference = new OpenApiReference 
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, 
                    Id = "API-Key"
                }
            },
            new string[] { }
        }
    }

operation.Security.Add(
    new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "Client-ID",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Reference = new OpenApiReference 
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, 
                    Id = "Client-ID"
                }
            },
            new string[] { }
        }
    }
);
```

And the result is like so

[Swagger Authorization Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vubz5.png)

with the curl request being generated correctly like so

`curl -X GET "https://localhost:44394/Configuration/application-key" -H  "accept: text/plain" -H  "API-Key: token" -H  "Client-ID: client-id"`

Importantly, I didn't want to have to define the requirement for the Client-ID by decorating each authorised endpoint with a [FromHeader] param or use a SwaggerHeader attribute etc I just want the two headers to be accessible via the Swagger UI so the user could authenticate their requests.

So my question, finally. I have decided that two values are required to authenticate a request but is this the right way to go about it, I mean in terms of convention etc. Or, should I go down a basic auth route, and provide the `Client-ID` as `username` and `API-Key` as `password`, or is there an alternative approach I may want to consider?

Side Note: This app is a little too simple to consider the use of JWT and the implementation of an authority service.