# ASP.NET Core API: Authentication popup is not showing up in Swagger UI

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with Swagger integrated using Swashbuckle. I have successfully integrated authorization on Swagger UI using an operation filter, because I do not want to show padlock for anonymous APIs.

```
.OperationFilter<AuthorizeFilter>()
```

Inside the filter, I have registered basic auth security requirement for Swagger UI.

My problem is, even though authentication is happening in APIs on Swagger UI, I no longer see that nice authentication popup which is giving when click on the padlock icon.

Could someone answer, why I am not seeing the auth popup now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 2023-04-17**: Updated security definition type to `Http` as per [@mimmoz81](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443174/mimmoz81)'s suggestion

---

Assuming you have some endpoints that protected with `[Authorize]` attribute (can also be put on the controller).

```cs
[Route("")]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("secure")]
    public IActionResult GetSomethingPrivate()
    {
        return Ok("secret");
    }

    [HttpGet("public")]
    public IActionResult GetSomethingPublic()
    {
        return Ok("hey");
    }
}
```

You need to define a security scheme suitable for your needs. **But do not require it globally, instead add it inside an operation filter**. Here I've added a simple token auth:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ApiPlayground", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("token", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Name = HeaderNames.Authorization,
            Scheme = "Bearer"
        });
        // dont add global security requirement
        // c.AddSecurityRequirement(/*...*/);
        c.OperationFilter<SecureEndpointAuthRequirementFilter>();
    });
}
```

And here's the operation filter which references the `token` auth scheme we've just created. It checks if the endpoint needs authentication, then adds the requirement.

```cs
internal class SecureEndpointAuthRequirementFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ApiDescription
            .ActionDescriptor
            .EndpointMetadata
            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
            .Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                [new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "token" }
                }] = new List<string>()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When you run the app, it works as you expect:

[image: swagger ui]

So does the auth popup:

[image: auth popup]

### Bonus: using basic auth

Define a new security scheme with following values:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        // ...
        // basic auth scheme (username + password)
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("basic", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            Scheme = "basic"
        });
        // dont add global security requirement
        // c.AddSecurityRequirement(/*...*/);
        c.OperationFilter<SecureEndpointAuthRequirementFilter>();
    });
}
```

Then update the operation filter to reference `basic` auth scheme:

```cs
internal class SecureEndpointAuthRequirementFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ApiDescription
            .ActionDescriptor
            .EndpointMetadata
            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
            .Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                [new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, 
                        Id = "basic" // <-- changed "token" -> "basic"
                    }
                }] = new List<string>()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

here's how the auth popup looks:

[image: basic auth popup]

After logging in, requests include the correct `Authorization` header.

[image: header]

Comment: thanks for the answer, what I have done is exactly same anyway, only change is I am using basic auth. Trying to figure out what is missing in my code.

Comment: @DarshaniJayasekara I've also added basic auth to my answer. See the update

Comment: Thanks, what was missing is the security definition. Security definition is the one which is giving the popup. Without that everything works, without showing the popup.

Comment: Swagger's docs is a fantastic resource. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/. Whenever something's not working right, check out the docs to see how your OpenAPI document differs, and add necessary configurations.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I am using **JWT Token Authentication** with **.NET Core API**. I Configure the swagger with the authorization token using the below code. This code will add global security requirements.

In Startup Class **ConfigureServices** Method.

```
        //Swagger Configuration

        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "API",
                Version = "v2",
                Description = "Your Api Description"
            });
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme (Example: 'Bearer 12345abcdef')",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });
            options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        }
                    },
                    Array.Empty<string>()
                }
            });
        });
```

And In **Configure** Method

```
        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
        });
```

After running the API project Authorize button will appear on the right side. On Click the authorize button Authorization popup open and then pass the token in the text box with '**Bearer  token**'.

Authorization working fine for me.

Comment: This will add a global security requirement. Not what OP asks.

Comment: I don't understand if this "global security requirement" could imply any risk, but it worked well for the scenarios I was able to think of for testing

Answer (score 1):

[@abdusco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298150/abdusco) answer was really great, but I had to slightly modify to `SecuritySchemeType.Http`, instead of `SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ApiPlayground", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("token", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http, // ----> HAD TO CHANGE THIS TO Http instead of ApiKey
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Name = HeaderNames.Authorization,
            Scheme = "Bearer"
        });
        // dont add global security requirement
        // c.AddSecurityRequirement(/*...*/);
        c.OperationFilter<SecureEndpointAuthRequirementFilter>();
    });
}
```

Doing this, I actually see the Bearer token auth popup style.

[image]

As of swagger docs https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the Abdusco's answer is true but modify the Apply method like this for `AllowAnonymousAttribute` Methods in `Authorized Controllers`

```
if (!context.ApiDescription
.ActionDescriptor
.EndpointMetadata
.OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
.Any() || context.ApiDescription
.ActionDescriptor
.EndpointMetadata
.OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>()
.Any())
{
    return;
}
```