# How can I remove the 'Authorize' button from a particular swagger doc?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I configure my swagger like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(
    options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc(
            IntegrationApiVersion, 
            new OpenApiInfo { Title = IntegrationApiName, Version = IntegrationApiVersion });
        options.SwaggerDoc(
            ApplicationApiVersion, 
            new OpenApiInfo { Title = ApplicationApiName, Version = ApplicationApiVersion });

        options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "Bearer Token: e.g. \"Bearer <your token here>\"",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Id = "Bearer",
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
            }
        });

        options.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
        options.EnableAnnotations();
        options.SchemaFilter<SmartEnumSchemaFilter>();

        options.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes();
        options.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
        options.IncludeXmlComments(
            Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"),
            includeControllerXmlComments: true);

        options.OperationFilter<TestOperationFilter>();
    })
.AddFluentValidationRulesToSwagger();
```

But since only 1 of my documents requires authentication `IntegrationApiVersion`, I want to hide the 'Authorize' button for the other doc. I found that the call to `AddSecutityDefinition` is what adds the button, but it does not let me define an api name/version, and I can't figure out how to set that definition from a filter

I managed to get the little locks to display, and JWT auth works great by adding this filter:

```
public class TestOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.DocumentName == SwaggerConfiguration.IntegrationApiVersion)
        {
            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header
                        },
                        Array.Empty<string>()
                    }
                }
            }; 
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to apply the same solution for the 'Authorize' button itself, so that it **only** appears on my `IntegrationApiVersion` page

The closes thing I could find was people doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61365691/4671754), but using something called `NonBodyParameter` to add a `SecurityDefinition` inside a filter, but it seems that type is no longer available to me. Does anyone have any advice?

Using SwashBuckle 6.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security definition gets add at the document level so you have to modify the document.

here I have written a document filter which removes the schema only for this document.

```
public class SwaggerDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        if(context.DocumentName == SwaggerConfiguration.ApplicationApiVersion)
        {
            swaggerDoc.Components.SecuritySchemes.Remove("Bearer");
        }
    }
}
```

hope it is helpful